# How does one use apps that place a menu on the system bar when the buttons are not in the screen?

Tags: user-interface, menu

I'm trying to use an app that places the hamburger menu on the system bar (with Home, Back, and Recent apps buttons). On devices that *have* a system bar (i.e., these buttons are on the screen), the menu is easily accessible. But now I'm trying to use the app on a device that has physical Home, Back, and Recent apps buttons. The system bar isn't shown, so the menu is apparently inaccessible (where it would be is off the screen). Is there a way to still access this menu when the system bar isn't shown?

Comment: @beeshyams Not rooted. It looks like that app is for a menu that controls system functions; I'm talking about a menu that is part of an individual app.

Comment: @beeshyams I was hoping for a native solution, but since none worked for me I tried this and it worked. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of Android solutions to this but here is a work around . This app [Menu Button](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jettoast.menubutton) , it doesn't require root and creates a virtual menu bar to manipulate the settings for your app by creating <kbd>Home</kbd> , <kbd>Back</kbd> and <kbd>Recents</kbd>

OP has [confirmed](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/188159/how-does-one-use-apps-that-place-a-menu-on-the-system-bar-when-the-buttons-are-n/188281#comment242755_188159) that it worked for them

Answer (score 1):

On many phones, long pressing on the back or recent apps button will bring up the menu.

If that doesn't work, here's a workaround: (this only works on Samsung phones)

Go to settings -> accessibility -> Dexterity and interaction -> Assistant menu, turn it on. There will now be a floating blue circle on your screen. Open the desired app, press on the circle, and press "more options" to should bring up the menu.

Comment: I can't find this setting on my phone.

Comment: @j_foster what phone do you have

Comment: Blu Tank Extreme Pro, running Android 7.0.

Comment: @j_foster oh apparently it only works on Samsung phone. My bad

Comment: Not a problem. It doesn't help me, but I'm sure it will be useful to someone else.