# Menu button for very old apps in Android 7

Tags: applications, buttons, menu

I have Lenovo TAB4 10 Plus tablet with Android 7.1.1 and I'm unable to change settings for some very old application because of missing menu button for them.

In Android 5 there was *floating menu button (with 3 vertical dots)*, and there was also a possibility (in general options of OS) to change the behavior of the task button - *long press on it opened the application menu*.

But now there is no floating menu, no possibility to change the behavior of task button (nor home button, nor back button).

I tried the long press / double tap on all three buttons (home, back, task) but without success.

Is there some way to display menu for such old applications?

**Edit:**

It's not a duplicate of the question
[How does one use apps that place a menu on the system bar when the buttons are not in the screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/188159/263472), because I tried using both answers in the question  but without a success - neither recommended procedures, nor the recommended application [Menu Button](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jettoast.menubutton) helped me. The last one created the (new) menu button, but it opened *Android settings*, not the active application's menu.

Comment: Have you checked your device's settings? There might be a possibility to assign the "menu" action to one of your navigation keys. I e.g. did that for double-tapping the "home" key.

Comment: @izzy, thanks, but I wrote in my question that I already tried it.

Comment: Even nothing like that? I've just literally translated from my German settings – where it is the last item in the "device" section, after "user" and "motions" (and before "location"). Holds things for the nav-keys like duration of background light, how the on/off button or the volume keys should behave …

Comment: @izzy, I have different menu items - "Locations" is in the "Personal" section, "Memory",  "Battery", and "Users" are the last 3 menu items in the "Device" section. Thank your very much for your effort to help me, I think that I browsed all thing in Settings but found nothing similar to your advice.

Comment: Sad – but if it's not there it cannot be used of course. Cleaning up comments a bit then. Good luck then with a non-root solution (though I doubt there is one)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you: [Xperia/AOSP NavBar Buttons](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gzplanet.xposed.xperianavbarbuttons). A pre requirement is root access and Xposed. I found only this alternative way for your device for the menu bar, but it might not worth.

Or try [Custom Navigation Bar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xyz.paphonb.systemuituner).

Comment: Is there something without need of rooted? Both your recommendation need rooted device and mine is not (and will not be).

Comment: 2nd app Custom navigation bar doesn't required root so try it other xda will help you for sure.

Comment: From [Custom Navigation Bar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xyz.paphonb.systemuituner): *"This requires a permission to be able to modify the navbar. You will need either root or a pc to grant it."*  - I don't know **how to grand that permision from PC**. Do you know?

Comment: U want to root your device?

Comment: Did u give it permission from setting/Accessibility/custom navigation bar and turn switch on their to give permission to access it

Comment: I have not such option in *Settings/Accessibility*, nor in other section of Setting. Is there *other* possibility for grand that permission?

Comment: No, I don´t want to root my device.

Comment: Is their was menu button before in your device and i thought u could Grant permission with adb with pc but im not sure but will try to help u.